# return value of cbegin function

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a code like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::string str{"My short string."};

    for (auto& it = str.cbegin(); it != str.cend(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it;

    return 0;
}
```

and I recieve an error: "initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue
"

I want to use `auto& it = str.cbegin()`, why I can't do do this? I suppose, cbegin returns an object of iterator, and I don't wanna copy it, so I use & syntax.

Could you explain, how cbegin works and what's it return value?

Comment: You cannot have a non-const reference to an r-value, which the returned iterator will be. You must assign it by value for your for loop to work as written.

Comment: *Why* don’t you want to copy the iterator? There’s probably some misunderstanding here.

Comment: the answer already explains in more detail, but iterators are already a lightweight indirection, you need not be afraid to copy it

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, I know that iterator is lightweight, but just faced this problem and my curiosity make me to ask that question.

Answer (score 5):

[`std::string::cbegin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/begin) returns iterator by value, what it returns is an rvalue and lvalue-reference to non-const can't bind to rvalue.

> I don't wanna copy it, so I use & syntax.

It's not heavy to copy iterator at all, so just

```
for (auto it = str.cbegin(); it != str.cend(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it;
```

Comment: Thank you for anser, I haven't managed to gather all information about standart library yet, I don't know about && syntax and how it works. I thought that it works like cbegin() { /*pa - pa - pa */ return iterator; } and thought that I can put a reference on it. Thank you!

Comment: @user2923317 use `auto&&` can be always correct(I mean it will always pass compile). Because it's a "forwarding reference"(a.k.a. universal reference), see refernce collapsing. But I think here using `auto` is enough.

Comment: Or better yet, `for (auto c : str) std::cout << c;`